# XCTestCase not launching application in setUp class method

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation, xctestcase

I am using XCode 8 and XCTestCase.  I created a class setUp function to be ran once before all tests, and the other setUp to be ran before each test case.

I want the application to be launched once before all test cases.  If I use the launch in the class setUp, it never gets executed.  If I use the launch in the setUp that is ran before each test, it does launch the test.

[image]

It prints:

IN CLASS SETUP

END CLASS SETUP

IN SETUP

IN TEST METHOD

But the application never gets launched.  If I uncomment the line to launch the application in the second setUp, it will get launched.

How can I have the application be launched once before all the tests in my test class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue and solved it the following way

```
class MyTestCase: XCTestCase {

    static var app: XCUIApplication?

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        if MyTestCase.app == nil {
            MyTestCase.app = XCUIApplication()
            MyTestCase.app!.launch()
        }
    }

    // Tests...
}
```

This will only launch the application at the first time the `setUp` method is called.

Comment: Thanks! This workaround does work for me.  Still curious about why it doesn't work in the class function that apple provides for the overall setup though.  But this will work until then! thanks much!

Comment: I learnt that no interaction with XCUIApplication will work in class methods, I think this may be a limitation of the way Xcode UI tests work.

Comment: This is really bad. Apple's XCUITest is basically not doing what it states it should allow:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods