# How to run swift XCTest tearDown once

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation, xctestcase

I am using xcode 8.3.3, swift, and I am trying to get the tearDown method to run only once.

I launch the application once with the solution provided here: 
[XCTestCase not launching application in setUp class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021466/xctestcase-not-launching-application-in-setup-class-method)

In the tearDown method, I want to logout of the application.  I only want to do this once.

The XCTest documentation has a class tearDown() method, but when I try to use it - it doesn't have access to the application anymore?:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods

This is all I get when I am in the tearDown method and so it can't access any elements on the application anymore:

[image]

How can I run the code in the tearDown just once at the end of all tests?

Comment: Do you mean at the end of all the tests throughout all your `XCTestCase`s or just at the end of the tests in the current `XCTestCase`?

Comment: After all of the tests in the current XCTestCase, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
import XCTest

class TestSuite: XCTestCase {

    static var testCount = testInvocations.count

    override func setUp()
    {
        super.setUp()

        TestSuite.testCount -= 1
    }

    override func tearDown()
    {
        if TestSuite.testCount == 0 {
            print("Final tearDown")
        }

        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testA() {}
    func testB() {}
    func testC() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This workaround will do for now :)   I really wish apple would provide overall test setUp and tearDown methods that work like they say they do!   The only change I needed to do was use "self.testInvocations().count" instead of "testInvocations.count"

Comment: I don't think you need the `self` part but the `()` might still be needed in swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

XCTestCase has two different setUp/tearDown combinations. One is at the individual test case level. The other is at the suite level. Just override the `class` versions to get the entire suite:

```
override class func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Your code goes here
}

override class func tearDown() {
    // Your code goes here
    super.tearDown()
}
```

Comment: Hi, i explained in the question why the class func didn't work for me.